# CRC8 Checksum with custom polynom in Python crcmod

Tags: python, crc, crc8

I'm trying to use crcmod to compute a crc checksum sent by a microcontroller with a custom polynom of 183 (decimal).

When I try to use

```
crc8 = crcmod.Crc(183)
```

I get

```
ValueError: The degree of the polynomial must be 8, 16, 24, 32 or 64
```

but

```
bin(183)
```

returns

```
'0b10110111'
```

which shows that IS a 8 bit polynom.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> The degree of the polynomial must be 8 ...

An 8 bit number is degree 7. Try 439, which is 183 + 256 (2^8).

Comment: Hmm, but this calculator allows for 183 (which is 0xB7). http://www.sunshine2k.de/coding/javascript/crc/crc_js.html and prints proper results.

Comment: @Julian - the error response mentioned "degree of polynomial", while the online CRC calculators typically don't use the most significant bit, since it's assumed to be 1. Based on the error response, try 439.